Gazebo force plugin missing error
I am running the Gazebo simulation but the robot is not correctly seen in the Gazebo environment and this error appeared.
muteeb@Muteeb:~/unitree_ros2$ ros2 launch go1_description gazebo_launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/muteeb/.ros/log/2024-09-11-01-39-55-488287-Muteeb-429694
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [429696]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [429698]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [429700]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [429702]
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247152004] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FL_calf
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247300839] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FL_calf_rotor
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247313714] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FL_foot
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247317027] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FL_hip
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247319495] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FL_hip_rotor
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247322331] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FL_thigh
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247324919] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FL_thigh_rotor
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247327466] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FR_calf
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247330024] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FR_calf_rotor
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247332596] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FR_foot
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247335138] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FR_hip
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247337754] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FR_hip_rotor
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247340187] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FR_thigh
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247342605] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FR_thigh_rotor
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247345058] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RL_calf
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247347457] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RL_calf_rotor
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247349896] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RL_foot
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247352252] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RL_hip
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247354582] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RL_hip_rotor
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247356985] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RL_thigh
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247359456] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RL_thigh_rotor
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247361850] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RR_calf
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247364240] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RR_calf_rotor
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247366612] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RR_foot
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247369002] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RR_hip
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247371343] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RR_hip_rotor
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247373764] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RR_thigh
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247376101] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RR_thigh_rotor
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247378532] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247381073] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_chin
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247383509] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_face
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247386024] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_laserscan_link_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247388791] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_laserscan_link_right
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247391180] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247393685] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_optical_chin
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247396161] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_optical_face
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247398539] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_optical_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247401019] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_optical_rearDown
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247403492] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_optical_right
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247405898] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_rearDown
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247408437] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_right
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247410996] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment imu_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247413393] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment trunk
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247415904] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ultraSound_face
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247418266] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ultraSound_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1725986396.247420631] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ultraSound_right
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1725986396.533265246] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1725986396.533475822] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic /robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-4]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1725986396.534680638] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on /robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1725986396.546269099] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1725986396.546448633] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1725986397.049180094] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1725986397.907896538] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [go1]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1725986397.922097529] [imu_plugin]: <initial_orientation_as_reference> is unset, using default value of false to comply with REP 145 (world as orientation reference)
[gzserver-1] [ERROR] [1725986398.016148644] [gazebo_ros_force]: Force plugin missing <link_name>, cannot proceed
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 429702]


